# gmap3 is not a function on yii2 body

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, jquery-gmap3

I create a fresh project yii2

into head tag i charge jquery google api and gmap with

```
<?php
    $this->head();
    Yii::$app->view->registerJsFile('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js',['position' => yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]);

    Yii::$app->view->registerJsFile('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false',['position' => yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]);
    Yii::$app->view->registerJsFile('/js/gmap3/dist/gmap3.js',['position' => yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]);
    ?>
```

and always in the head put this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#test1').gmap3({
      marker:{
        address: "Haltern am See, Weseler Str. 151"
      },
      map:{
        options:{
          zoom: 14
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The problem is in the body section

if i use this code

```
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
   <div id="test1" class="gmap3"></div>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
```

NOT WORK

if i use this code

```
<?php //$this->beginBody() ?>
   <div id="test1" class="gmap3"></div>
<?php //$this->endBody() ?>
```

IT WORK

The beginBody function make conflict with gmap3

Firebug tell me

TypeError: $(...).gmap3 is not a function
$('#test1').gmap3({

Comment: maybe you have included the library twice!

Comment: Have you tried putting the ```$this->head();```after the ```Yii::$app->view->registerJsFile()```calls? Also its not clear that exactly where you are putting your javascript code, i mean in which file?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for tip.

The problem was default point (of yii2) of charge jquery: at bottom page into .
I solved add default jquery position to head section.
I modify the file AppAsset.php and i add the follow code into AppAsset class

```
public $jsOptions = array('position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD);
```

After into main.php (view/layout folder)

```
<?php
    Yii::$app->view->registerJsFile('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false',['position' => yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]);
    $this->head();    
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmap3/dist/gmap3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#test1').gmap3({
      marker:{
        address: "Haltern am See, Weseler Str. 151"
      },
      map:{
        options:{
          zoom: 14
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
```

Thanks!